# Unable to get provider (ClassNotFoundException) Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, android-database

I am working on a Solution in Xamarin which contains at least 4 different Android Applications.

My Goal is to create a shared content provider for all of these four apps so that I can have the Master data in one place (If an application updates that data, I can get that updated version in another app).

In Visual Studio, I have create a PCL project where I have defined the Content provider (which I can reference in all applications and do the CRUD operations).

My Content Provider is as follows:

```
namespace com.cybertron.android.Provider
{
    public class SectionProvider : ContentProvider
    {
        SectionDatabase sectDb;
        public const string AUTHORITY = "com.cybertron.android.Provider.SectionProvider";
        public const string SECTIONS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CursorDirBaseType + "/vnd.com.cybertron.android.sections";
        public const string SECTION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CursorItemBaseType + "/vnd.com.cybertron.android.section";
        static string BASE_PATH = "sections";
        static UriMatcher uriMatcher = BuildUriMatcher();
        public static readonly Android.Net.Uri CONTENT_URI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH);
        const int GET_ALL = 0;
        const int GET_ONE = 1;
        public static class SectionConsts
        {
            public const string SectNo = "SectNo";
            public const string KeyPos = "Key";
            public const string Date = "Date";
            public const string UnitID = "UnitID";
        }

        static UriMatcher BuildUriMatcher()
        {
            var matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NoMatch);

            matcher.AddURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, GET_ALL); 
            matcher.AddURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", GET_ONE);
            return matcher;
        }
        public override bool OnCreate()
        {
            sectDb = new SectionDatabase(Context);
            return true;
        }        

        public override string GetType(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            switch (uriMatcher.Match(uri))
            {
                case GET_ALL:
                    return SECTIONS_MIME_TYPE; // list
                case GET_ONE:
                    return SECTION_MIME_TYPE; // single item
                default:
                    throw new Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
            }
        } 
.
.
.        
    }
}
```

I have referenced my project in my Xamarin Application project. I did not put the `ContentProvider` attribute because I learned that gives out `INSALL_FAILED_CONFLICT` error if two applications use the same one. Instead I put that in the manifest file as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="com.cybertron.android.bluecork"
                android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <application android:label="com.cybertron.android.bluecork.blueapp">
    <provider
          android:name="com.cybertron.android.Provider.SectionProvider"
          android:authorities="com.cybertron.android.Provider.SectionProvider"
          android:exported="true" />
  </application>          
</manifest>
```

When I try to debug this application I get an error up front (when the app starts in the emulator)

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.cybertron.android.Provider.SectionProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   com.cybertron.android.Provider.SectionProvider on path:
>   DexPathList......

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error. Secondly, I would like to know if it is possible for multiple applications to share one database on Android Systems?

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can use a SQlite database and access it from multiple apps as long as it's stored outside of the applications install directory. Thatw ay it shouldn't get removed when one of your apps is uninstalled. I'm not sure if that's the same for what you're trying to do above.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt That may achieve the purpose as well. Do you know how I can create a SQLite db outside of my app? What I am looking for is a database that can be accessed by multiple applications. How can that be achieved.

Comment: some of the basics can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/  realistically you should just need to ensure the path the database is stored at is accessible by your other applications, and then essentially do a check/create if the databse exists or needs to be created (this would depend on the order in which your apps are installed, as they would all need to check that the database either already exists at the path location, or if it doesn't, then create it.)

Comment: Thanks @Digitalsa1nt I already know how to create Databases in Xamarin. In Xamarin when we create a DB with the help of the DBHelper it automatically puts that in the package.