# Creating SQLite database on Internal storage ANDROID

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a SQLIte database on Internal Storage in my Xamarin application. I am creating a system for an offline environment where at least 3 applications are inter-connected with shared data. So if one application creates some data the other application should be able to read that.

The Database project is a Portable Class Library which I plan to include in all three applications.

My DbHelper is as follows:

```
public Database()
{
    string folder = "/data/data/Anchor.Main";
    _dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Anchor.db");

    try
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder); //Getting error here
        }

        _connection = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        _connection.CreateTable<Orders>();
        _connection.CreateTable<Items>();    

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {  }

}
```

I get error which says

> Access to the path "/data/data/Anchor.Main" is denied.

Following is the stack trace

> at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path)
>   [0x0004b] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00075] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   anchorapp.db.Helper.Database..ctor () [0x0002e]

I understand this is because of the permissions, but what permissions do I need to set in order to write to the Internal storage from a PCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by creating a sharedId within my projects and using the SharedContext to access the databases created by other apps

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing Android system folder of "/data/data/Anchor.Main".
Your app internal storage will be in

```
/data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files
```

You can use the following code to get the folder to store the database:

```
// Equal to /data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files
var homePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
_dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(homePath, "Anchor.db");
_connection = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
```

Comment: I can do that but I need other apps to access the DB created by this application. Is it possible to read data from a database that is created by another database?

Comment: You can define android:sharedUserId in your manifest to enable 2 app to share datas. However, you should consider whether your apps really need to use this approach. Check out ContentProvider and see whether it can fulfill what you plan to do with your apps first.

Comment: I tried with the content provider, that resulted in a different error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074287/unable-to-get-provider-classnotfoundexception-xamarin 

I definitely need to access the database, of atleast 1 application out of the 3. How can I do it with the sharedId.

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS does not work that way. Each platform keeps apps in a sandboxed environment. If you want to create and store data in your app you need to create the path like the following sample:

```
var docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
_dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(docFolder, "Anchor.db");
```

Also set the permissions ReadExternalStorage and WriteExternalStorage in your Android project

Instead of writing to a private folder, you could create the database in a public one. To do so the docFolder would change to:

```
var docFolder = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "YourDirectoryName");
```

Please be advised, that if you go that way everyone can see and open the database.

Comment: I can do that but I need other apps to access the DB created by this application. Is it possible to read data from a database that is created by another database?